# Error "Index: 0, Size: 0" while using AWSUtility::CloudFormation::CommandRunner in cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

We are trying to run few bash commands in cloud formation template in AWS.

We followed the following blog of AWS to run CommandRunner utilty in cloud formation template.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/running-bash-commands-in-aws-cloudformation-templates/

```yaml
Resources:
    CommandRunner:
        Type: AWSUtility::CloudFormation::CommandRunner
        Properties: 
            Command: 'echo HelloWorld > /command-output.txt'

Outputs:
  Op1:
    Description: Test output
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt: CommandRunner.Output
```

Facing following error while running command utility in cloud formation template.

```
Resource handler returned message: "Index: 0, Size: 0" (RequestToken: c99903a7-****-0c58-010c-4fa03699fcfd, HandlerErrorCode: InternalFailure)
```

Stack ID(s) / Stack ARN: arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-2:******:stack/comandrunner-test-iops*/ **

The error message is not descriptive enough to identify the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When contacted AWS Supported team, they gave the following response.

> The Index: 0, Size: 0 error usually happens because you may not have a
> default VPC in the eu-west-2 region (P.S.: I am not able to verify
> this since I do not have access to your account).
>
> In general, CommandRunner uses the default VPC to run the command, but
> when it doesn’t exist this error is thrown. You can still run the
> CommandRunner without a default VPC, by specifying the SubnetId
> property.
>
> I also found an active issue pulled in on the github repository to
> improve the error handling for this error when it occurs on
> CloudFormation.

After their response, we added Subnet id and security group id to the template.

Give private subnet id.

```yaml
Parameters:
  ReqSubnetId:
    Type: String
    Description: Please enter Subnet id so that command runner can execute
    Default: subnet-0sampleid28474
    
  ReqSecurityGroupId:
    Type: String
    Description: Please enter security group id so that command runner can execute
    Default: sg-03samplesecuritygroupid


Resources:
    CommandRunner:
        Type: AWSUtility::CloudFormation::CommandRunner
        Properties: 
            Command: 'echo HelloWorld > /command-output.txt'
            SubnetId: !Ref ReqSubnetId
            SecurityGroupId: !Ref ReqSecurityGroupId
            

Outputs:
  Op1:
    Description: Test output
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt: CommandRunner.Output
```

Options supported for `Type: AWSUtility::CloudFormation::CommandRunner` are

```yaml
Type: AWSUtility::CloudFormation::CommandRunner
Properties:
    Command: String
    Role: String
    LogGroup: String
    SubnetId: String
    KeyId: String
    SecurityGroupId: String
```

Reference: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-resource-providers-awsutilities-commandrunner/tree/master/docs#yaml